# Asana: Can I add API call on Asana Workflow Action?

Tags: asana, asana-api, asana-connect

Currently, it seems that Asana Workflow Action does not support skipping weekends in due date calculation, which is achievable in NodeJS. I am thinking if we can let it make an API call whenever a task has been moved into a certain section so that my server can calculate the correct due date for it and update the task, it would enable us to skip the weekends. Is that something possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it is not possible. But we can use Asana Webhook to track the same trigger of Workflow Action and do the API call we want to do there.